# Unity3D - GameObject.Find() returning null for disabled object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a game object that at the beginning of the game is disabled. Then I want to enable it later via script. So far I have tried to use the following code:

```
GameObject.Find("name").SetActive (true);
```

The problem is that as the game object at the beginning is disabled when I do

```
GameObject.Find("name")
```

I get null. So I don't know how to activate it. It's a canvas.

Comment: Is the name definitely correct?

Comment: like rhughes mentions, you need to define name correctly.

Comment: Do you necessarily need to disable the `GameObject`? Could you just disable one of its *components* instead, such as a `Renderer`, `Rigidbody`, and/or `Collider`?

Answer (score 9):

You can create a class variable in your script, and then in the Unity scene editor assign your disabled object to that class variable.

For example:

In your script file, create the class variable:

```
public GameObject objectToEnable;
```

Then, in the scene editor, the "objectToEnable" variable will appear on the Script component of the object containing your script. Simply drag your disabled object to that variable (in the scene editor) to set the reference.

Once you do that, at runtime you can just do:

```
objectToEnable.SetActive(true);
```

The reference should still be valid, even if the object is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You could first save the object in a variable, for example you first declare a variable that will hold the object

```
 GameObject tempVar; //this line goes outside any function, not in Start or Update
```

Then in the Start or Awake function you find the object and save it

```
 tempVar = GameObject.Find("name"); // this line goes in Start, just before you disable the object
 tempVar.SetActive(false);  //now the object is disabled but saved in a variable with which you can access it at any time
```

Of course, this code assumes the object is NOT disabled before the game starts.